# Copy Only Missing Files

Tags: batch-file

Let me preface this question by saying that I am relatively new to writing batch files, so I apologize if my question seems remedial.

I'm trying to move files from a directory to a shared drive that I have mapped.  I know that using "XCOPY c:\etc.. z:\etc.. /Y" will copy everything from one place to another, but what I don't want to do is overwrite every file every time.  Is there a way to copy just the files that are not located in the destination directory?

Comment: @Joey: Excuse me, how do you achieve this task in Windows? I mean, in an easier way than just type one command and press Enter? I am curios...

Comment: Aacini, I was picking on the [tag:ms-dos] tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### solution 1 :

```
xcopy  /d/y
```

should work..........

[image]

### solution 2

```
echo "No" | copy/-Y c:\source c:\Dest\
```

working. tested

2 folders have the same files , lets try to copy.

```
 C:\r\Roi>echo "No" | copy/-Y  . 2
.\DSpubring.pkr
Overwrite 2\DSpubring.pkr? (Yes/No/All): "No"
Overwrite 2\DSpubring.pkr? (Yes/No/All):
.\DSsecring.skr
Overwrite 2\DSsecring.skr? (Yes/No/All):
        0 file(s) copied.
```

lets create 1 new file

```
C:\r\Roi>copy con g.txt
sdfsdf
^Z
    1 file(s) copied.
```

lets copy :

```
C:\r\Roi>echo "No" | copy/-Y  . 2
.\DSpubring.pkr
Overwrite 2\DSpubring.pkr? (Yes/No/All): "No"
Overwrite 2\DSpubring.pkr? (Yes/No/All):
.\DSsecring.skr
Overwrite 2\DSsecring.skr? (Yes/No/All):
.\g.txt
        1 file(s) copied. <------------ one file only
```

Comment: Ok so the command that I am using is xcopy c:\test\*.* z:\ /d/y and it is still copying everything.

Comment: @BigBrown - The command will only copy newer versions. If no changes have been made to files in source folder, then when you run the command a second time it should not copy anything.

Comment: Hi Royi - it's not for me. I was just explaining to @BigBrown how your original answer worked :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
robocopy /xc /xn /xo /s source destination
```

Answer taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/466090/how-to-copy-only-those-files-that-are-not-in-the-destination).